# Angular velocity formula in a precession motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, angular-velocity, precession

I find out that in the specific case of a precession motion of a constant in magnitude vector $\vec{A}$ we can say that: $\frac{d\vec{A}}{dt}=\vec{\omega}$x$\vec{A}$. Where $\vec{\omega}$ is the angular velocity.
I can't understand why we can say it, and how can I reach that formula by derivating $\vec{A}$. [image: precession]

Comment: $A$ is _not_ a constant vector. It does not change magnitude, but it does change direction.

Comment: Right, I'll correct it.